Buy units of a good - If you buy them together, you get a discount - Find the cheapest way to purchase all goods available
The problem is as follows: A user needs to be able to purchase goods. He has a total of five distinct goods available: I've called them '1', '2', '3', '4', and '5',
If the user buys them in sets, he gets a discount. However, to get the discounts, each set must contain at most one unit of each good. e.g. a set of '1' and '2' would get a discount. Two times '1' would not. The discounts are: 5% for two units, 10% for 3 units, 20% for 4 units, and 25% for all five.
My problem is: Find the way to purchase all goods you want by which minimizes costs.
This is the algorithm I used, and I'm very confident it works. Here I'll explain it.
I resolved it the following way:

Find the purchase number that is most "lucrative". To me, that means: when increasing the number of units to be purchased, how does the total prize increase? The one that has the lowest increase, is the most "lucrative".

a) it costs $8 to buy one unit
b) when buying two, if it's two times $8, minus 5% discount, total prize is $15.20, an increase of $7.20
c) three units, the total prize with discount is $21.60, an increase of $6.40
d) four units, the total prize with discount is $25.60, an increase of $4
e) five units, the total prize with discount is $30, an increase of $4.4
In this example, buying 4 units has the lowest total increase, so it's the most "lucrative".
The total ranking is: 4>5>3>2>1

try and minimize the number of purchases. In particular, it means: The good that has the highest number of "to-be-purchased" is the maximum number of purchases we will make. In practice, that means: Although purchasing 4 goods at once might be the most lucrative, it must be kept within this maximum. Imagine you need to purchase 2 units of each 5 units: You can't purchase two times four, and then the rest, because that would go over the maximum. So you have to purchase two times all 5

However, imagine you need to purchase 2x1,2x2,2x3,1x4, and 1x5: You can purchase once all 5 and once the remaining 3. However, purchasing 4 units is more lucrative. As such, purchasing two times 4 units is the preferred solutions, and minimizes the costs.
If there are several ways to purchase all units that remains within this "maximum" purchases, then the ones that have the most lucrative ones are preferred.
Here is the code I used to resolve it. It works perfectly, however, I'd appreciate advice on how to format it better, clean it better, and so on.
public class Main {
    
    static final int SELECTION = 5;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        DiscountOptimization.validityCheck(SELECTION);
        DiscountOptimization.initalization();
        
        try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)){
            
            Map<String, Integer> unitAvailability = new HashMap<>();
        
            while(true) {
            
                System.out.printf("""
                    Enter number between 1 and %d.\n""", SELECTION);
                
                if(unitAvailability.isEmpty()) {
                    
                    System.out.println("""
                        To end the program, leave the input empty and press enter!""");
                }else {
                    
                    System.out.println("""
                        To begin the analysis, leave the input empty and press enter!""");
                }
            
            
                String input = scanner.nextLine();
            
                if(isEnter(input) && unitAvailability.isEmpty()) {
                
                    break;
                }else if(isEnter(input) && !unitAvailability.isEmpty()) {
                
                    System.out.println("""
                        The goods with the following availability should be 
                        purchased: """+ unitAvailability);
                
                    List<Set<String>> result = DiscountOptimization.purchaseAllUnits(unitAvailability);
                
                    System.out.println(resultPresentation(result));
                    
                    System.out.println("""
                            -------------------------
                            new evaluation from here
                            -------------------------
                            """);
                    unitAvailability = new HashMap<>();
                }else if(!input.matches("\\d+")) {
                
                    System.out.println("""
                        \nError!! The input was not an integer. The input will 
                        not be considered.\n""");
                }else if(Integer.valueOf(input)<1 
                        || Integer.valueOf(input) > SELECTION) {
                    
                    System.out.printf("""
                        \nError!! The input is invalid. Valid number are between 1
                        and %d. The input can not be considered.\n\n""", SELECTION);
                }else {
                
                    unitAvailability.put(input, 
                            unitAvailability.getOrDefault(input, 0) + 1);
                
                    System.out.printf("""
                            \n%s was added. Current availability: """
                            +unitAvailability+"\n\n", input);
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            
            System.out.println("\nThe program was ended!\n");
        }
    }
    
    public static boolean isEnter(String fInput) {
        return "".equals(fInput);
    }

    private static String resultPresentation(List<Set<String>> result) {
        
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        
        sb.append("""
            \nTo purchase all goods with the minimum prize, you should 
            purchase them in the following combinations:\n""");
        
        result.forEach(entry -> 
            sb.append("Combination ").append(entry)
                .append(String.format(" for the prize of %.2f %n", 
                 
            DiscountOptimization.getPrizeForUnitNumber(entry.size())
                .doubleValue()))
        );
        
        sb.append("The total sum is ")
             
       .append(String.format("%.2f",
        DiscountOptimization.calculateTotalSum(result).doubleValue()))
       .append("\n");
        
        return sb.toString();
    }
}

public class DiscountOptimization {
    
    static final BigDecimal BOOK_PRIZE = new BigDecimal("8.00");
    
    static final double[] DISCOUNTS = new double[] {0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.25};

    static final Map<String, BigDecimal> prizeMap = new HashMap<>();
    
    private static List<String> lucrRanking;
    
    private DiscountOptimization() {}


    public static BigDecimal calculateTotalSum(List<Set<String>> fPurchasedCombos) {
        
        BigDecimal finalSum = new BigDecimal("0.00");
        
        for(Set<String> currSet: fPurchasedCombos) {
            
            finalSum = finalSum.add(prizeMap.get(String.valueOf(currSet.size())));
        }
        
        return finalSum;
    }
    
    
    public static List<Set<String>> purchaseAllUnits(Map<String, Integer> availUnits){
        
        if(availUnits == null) {
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }
        
        List<Set<String>> resultSet = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> currentRanking = new ArrayList<>(lucrRanking);
        
        while(!availUnits.isEmpty()) {
            
            currentRanking = currentRanking.stream()
                .filter(ent -> Integer.valueOf(ent) <= availUnits.entrySet().size())
                .toList();
            
            resultSet.add(
                newPurchase(calcUnitNumber(availUnits, currentRanking), availUnits)
            );
        }
        
        return resultSet;
    }
    
    
    private static Set<String> newPurchase(int setLimit, 
            Map<String, Integer> availUnits){
        
        Set<String> newPurchaseSet = new HashSet<>();
        
        while(newPurchaseSet.size() != setLimit) {
            
            String nextUnit = nextUnitToPurchase(newPurchaseSet, availUnits);
            newPurchaseSet.add(nextUnit);
            availUnits.put(nextUnit, availUnits.get(nextUnit)-1);
            
            if(availUnits.get(nextUnit)==0) {
                
                availUnits.remove(nextUnit);
            }
        }
        
        return newPurchaseSet;
    }
    
    
    private static String nextUnitToPurchase(Set<String> purchasedSet, 
            Map<String, Integer> availUnits) {
        
        Set<Entry<String, Integer>> currentSet = 
            new HashSet<>(availUnits.entrySet());
            
        currentSet = currentSet.stream()
            .filter(entry -> ! purchasedSet.contains(entry.getKey()))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        
        return Collections.max(currentSet, 
            Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).getKey();
    }
    
    
    private static int calcUnitNumber(Map<String, Integer> availUnits, 
            List<String> currentRanking) {
        
        Optional<Integer> maxRemain =
                availUnits.values().stream().max(Comparator.comparing(x -> x));
        
        if(maxRemain.isEmpty()) {
            
            return -1;
        }
        
        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>(availUnits.values());
        int frequency = Collections.frequency(numbers, maxRemain.get());
        
        return Math.max(frequency, Integer.valueOf(currentRanking.get(0)));
    }
    
    
    public static void initalization() {
        
        Map<String, BigDecimal> valueIncreases = new HashMap<>();
        
        IntStream.range(1, DISCOUNTS.length+1).forEach(x -> {
            
            prizeMap.put(String.valueOf(x), 
                    BigDecimal.valueOf(BOOK_PRIZE.intValue()*x*(1-DISCOUNTS[x-1])));
            
            valueIncreases.put(String.valueOf(x), prizeMap.get(String.valueOf(x))
                    .subtract(prizeMap.getOrDefault(String.valueOf(x-1), 
                    new BigDecimal("0.00"))));
        });
        
        List<Entry<String, BigDecimal>> list 
            = new ArrayList<>(valueIncreases.entrySet());
        list.sort(Entry.comparingByValue());
        
        lucrRanking = list.stream().map(Entry::getKey).toList();
    }
    

    public static void validityCheck(int selection) {
        
        if(selection != DISCOUNTS.length) {
            
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("""
                the length of the array 'DISCOUNTS' must be identical 
             to 'selection'""");
        }else if(IntStream.range(1,DISCOUNTS.length)
                .anyMatch( x-> DISCOUNTS[x-1]>DISCOUNTS[x])) {
            
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("""
                    To use this program, the discounts must increase 
                    with the number of purchased units""");
        }
    }
    
    public static BigDecimal getPrizeForUnitNumber(int numberUnits) {
        
        return prizeMap.get(String.valueOf(numberUnits));
    }
}


Stream abuse
When you need to manipulate the elements of an array or list using their indices, an indexed based for-loop is the appropriate tool, not a Stream.
That's a clearly an abuse of IntStream.range():
IntStream.range(1, DISCOUNTS.length + 1).forEach(x -> {
            
    prizeMap.put(String.valueOf(x),
        BigDecimal.valueOf(BOOK_PRIZE.intValue()*x*(1-DISCOUNTS[x-1])));
            
    valueIncreases.put(String.valueOf(x), prizeMap.get(String.valueOf(x))
        .subtract(prizeMap.getOrDefault(String.valueOf(x-1),
            new BigDecimal("0.00"))));
});

This stream is created for the sole purpose of performing side-effects via Stream.forEach(), which is discouraged by the Stream API (as I've mentioned here, although the code is unrelated you're repeating the same mistake).
Don't mimic for-loops with streams, and avoid multiline lambda expressions.
"Extract method" Refactoring technic
This basic refactoring aims to improve code readability by moving self-contained logic into separate, descriptively named methods.
For example, this chuck of code from the snippet above:
BigDecimal.valueOf(BOOK_PRIZE.intValue()*x*(1-DISCOUNTS[x-1]))

should be replaced with a method call that takes array index as a parameter.
Another example:
else if(IntStream.range(1,DISCOUNTS.length)
    .anyMatch( x-> DISCOUNTS[x-1]>DISCOUNTS[x]))

Newer put streams into an if-statement, introduce a method describing this condition instead.
All major IDEs have support for basic refactorings for quite a while. If you're using IntelliJ, Ctrl + Alt + M is a short-cut for method extraction.
Unnecessary Boxing
Integer.valueOf() produces Integer wrapper-type, don't use this method when primitive int is sufficient. Use Integer.parseInt() in such cases instead:
Integer.valueOf(input) < 1 -> Integer.parseInt(input) < 1
Formatting
Don't skimp on whitespace, it's missing in many places in your code.
According to code conventions for Java language

A keyword followed by a parenthesis should be separated by a space
while (true) {
    ... 
} 



All binary operators except . should be separated from their operands by spaces.
a += c + d;
a = (a + b) / (c * d);


I.e. instead of this:
if(maxRemain.isEmpty()) { ... }

BOOK_PRIZE.intValue()*x*(1-DISCOUNTS[x-1])

you should have this
if (maxRemain.isEmpty()) { ... }

BOOK_PRIZE.intValue() * x * (1 - DISCOUNTS[x - 1])

Use your IDE to help with formatting. Ctrl + Alt + L is a short-cut in IntelliJ.
Minor suggestions
new BigDecimal("0.00") -> BigDecimal.ZERO
max(Comparator.comparing(x -> x)) -> max(naturalOrder()) *
* use static imports to improve readability import static java.util.Comparator.naturalOrder;

Do not hard-code SELECTION. That should be derived from a (non-static) accessor method on DiscountOptimization. Remove validityCheck, and construct the program so that that selection size is naturally valid.
The input loop is fairly awkward - currently you're asking the user to build up an integer in increments of 1! If they want to express a quantity of 5000 for product 3, they will need to iterate 5000 times. Instead, just ask for a count integer for each product the user cares about.
When calling printf, write %n instead of \n for portability.
prize is probably incorrect in context, and you should write price.
purchaseAllUnits mutates its argument availUnits when it should not. The safest thing to do is make a copy of the map.
DISCOUNTS and BOOK_PRICE should not be hard-coded; instead, make them instance members set upon construction.
initalization needs to be removed and reframed as a constructor.
The output is in a very inconvenient form - there's a new row for every single combination, when there should only be a new row for every unique combination with an associated count.
During your construction of priceMap and valueIncreases, proper use of streams would look like
        priceMap = IntStream.range(1, 1 + discounts.length)
            .collect(
                // Collectors.toMap can only be used on a boxed() stream
                HashMap::new,
                (map, x) -> map.put(
                    x,
                    book_price_cents*x*(1 - discounts[x - 1])
                ),
                HashMap::putAll
            );

        Map<Integer, Double> valueIncreases = IntStream.range(1, 1 + discounts.length)
            .collect(
                HashMap::new,
                (map, x) -> map.put(
                    x,
                    priceMap.get(x) - priceMap.getOrDefault(x - 1, 0.)
                ),
                HashMap::putAll
            );

However, since you're using a continuous integer series as a key, maps shouldn't be used at all; use arrays or lists instead.
I'll dig into the algorithm more later.

The refactored streams you presented align with recommendations of the Stream API spec. However, there's an imperative aspect to this code because IntStream.range().collect() iterates over array indexes in an obvious way, turning a stream into an external iterator that controls the iteration process in the same way an indexed-based for-loop does that.

While Java 8 Streams were designed as internal iterators meant to focus solely on what to do with stream elements, abstracting away the actual mechanism of how the next element is being provided. In cases like this, where Arrays.stream() can not be applied, I would prefer an index-based for-loop over a stream closely mimicking it (in this case, range() is a direct replacement of the initialization and condition parts of a for-loop).

Re. double - note that OP never transmits, serializes or stores the value in any way, and always displays it rounded to cents. Between that and a convex optimization routine where, depending on design, it's mandatory to drop down in and out of double, doing so is clearly not a problem here, and is the simpler choice.

@AlexanderIvanchenko Re. streams - I don't find those reasons compelling, but anyway: my example is how to use streams should OP continue to use streams, not "streams are the best way to do this".

example is how to use streams should OP continue to use streams, not "streams are the best way to do this" - and I acknowledged in my comment that you provided correct spec-aligned examples.

If you just meant, that the scope of using double is limited only to the implementation of this algorithm, then I agree that it's fine and there will be no harm. But it's probably worth to clarify that (so that readers will not misinterpret your intention).
